# Scraping an easy site with response post / get

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get response from an easy (apparently) HTML page:   https://www.webdesign-flash.ro/vs/ (it encodes the postetd link)
My code:

```
url = 'https://www.webdesign-flash.ro/vs/'

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
to_encrypt = {'getPass':'https://en.wikipedia.org/'}

session = requests.Session()
resp    = session.post(url, data=to_encrypt, headers=headers)  # resp.status_code here is 200

x = session.get(url, headers=headers)  # resp.status_code here is also 200
```

The requested part of response should look like: 
encrypt:aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cud2ViZGVzaWduLWZsYXNoLnJvL3ZzLw==

However the response body is empty.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new in this, so exactly not sure, but I think the issue might be the following:

```
<body style="background-color:#aaaaaa; padding:0px; margin:20px;">
                <input id="getPass"></input>
                <button type="button" onclick="encript()">Encrypt media</button>
                <p id="result"></p>
        </body>
```

There was a button that need to be clicked, if you go to the website and clicked the button, and then press F12 to inspect the elements, you will see the result contains the encrypted answer.

```
<p id="result">encrypt:aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnLw==</p>
```

You can see how to click the button using python. Many uses selenium.
Thank You

Comment: I've installed selenium and geckodriver. However `webdriver.get('https://www.webdesign-flash.ro/vs/')` shows TimeOut error while in normal Firefox opening it allright. webdriver connects also to a test pages like https://www.google.com/

Comment: I was able to see the page. Did you install chromedriver? geckodriver is for firefox.

Comment: It looks like it was a problem of firefox. Chromedriver connects allright ...